# Windows 7 partition not showing on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mount, windows-7

I use Ubuntu 13.04 on a dual boot with Windows 7.

I could see the Windows partition until I did a hard reset because the computer froze.

I read about using a manual mount, however the **blkid** just doesn't do anything, and never shows any output.

Source:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Both systems are bootable however and the filesystems seem to be fine.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount | grep '^/'`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4wy6P4GT @Alaa

Comment: Have you tried booting a Iive cd and running the program boot repair?

Comment: No, what should I do from the live cd? Does it matter if the live cd is not 13.04? @Bryan

Comment: @Bryan Boot repair is a tool used to repair boot problems. FunKy says he can boot both systems, it's just that he doesn't see the Windows partition anymore in Ubuntu, and he needs to manually mount it.

Comment: ahh I neglected the last sentence. Sorry about the FunKy.

Comment: Np. How long does blkid take to run? Maybe I haven't waited enough (I've been waiting for about 15 minutes).

Comment: Make sure you use `sudo blkid`. Without `sudo` it won't show anything.

Comment: I've managed to get the UUID with "ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/".
I want to mount my C:\ folder on read-only, I now add a link to my current fstab and how I think it should look, please tell me if this looks right.
http://pastebin.com/dbbp8wmE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, here's what I suggest adding to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=BA361D27361CE5E3    /media/Data    ntfs    ro,auto,user,exec,umask=003     0    0
```

The explanation of the options are as follows:

- `ro` mounts it as read-only.
- `auto` ensures that it's automatically mounted. You may wish to remove this.
- `user` allows other users to mount the filesystem. This option automatically implies `noexec`, `nodev`, and `nosuid`.
- `exec` allows you to run executables from the drive. Putting this will override the automatically implied `noexec` from the `user` option. You may wish to remove this if you don't plan on running executables (i.e. applications, and installations).
- `umask=003` sets the permissions to `rwxrwxr--`. It's just a set of relaxed permissions that allow you to basically have access to everything.

The last option (`umask`) sets the `write` permission, but you already have the drive mounted as `ro`, so you won't be able to write anything. But this makes it simpler if you ever want to mount it as read-write in the future; just do `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/Data`.

Don't forget to make sure that `/media/Data` is created.

Once you've added your `fstab` entry, do `sudo mount -a` to apply the settings.